# How do you populate information from a user's AD profile to a list's field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, active-directory-import

Basically I want to create a Staff Directory on SharePoint that auto-populates a user's location (we are multi-site), Phone Number, and Title.  I am hoping to automate some of this process by pulling these bits of data from the user's AD profile.  Basically making it easier for the HR users to add the person into the list by only needing to add the name/profile into the beginning, but also allowing easy changing when a person moves location/phone number/job title.

Thanks,
-Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person/group column allows you to select which information to pull from the profile. So if you wanted to display Name, Phone Number, and Title, you would add 3 person/group columns, then choose the corresponding "Show field" option. Then you just select the same person for all 3 fields and they will stay in sync from AD as long as your profile sync job is running.

[image]

**UPDATE WITH WORKFLOW**

`Set field in current item`

[image]

Comment: This definitely helps, but I was hoping for something a little more automated.  This gives me a jumping point for maybe using Workflows to populate the other fields.  Thanks Erin.

Comment: I do use a workflow to set this field on my contacts lists. I have a field for Name, Job Title, Phone, Mobile, and E-Mail. When I create a new item, I fill out Name and use a workflow to set all the other fields equal to name.

Comment: I am new to Workflows (and SharePoint in general)  Could you post your pseudocode for me to analyze?  It would be a great help, and it sounds like what I am attempting to do.

Comment: Added screenshot of workflow step to my post